# Intent Action doesn't work in implicit intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
Intent n = new Intent("com.bushraod.sendM.hom");
n.putExtra("name", nam);
startActivityForResult(n, 1);
```

I wrote this code and it doesn't work to move to another activity.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: which `Activity` you want to run?

Comment: Do you want to pass any value from one activity to another or simply want to navigate to another activity..?

Answer (score 0):

For moving to another activity, use something like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra("name", name);
intent.setPackage("com.bushraod.sendM.hom"); //Package name of the application you are trying to open
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to another activity, you can just do the following:

```
Intent n = new Intent(this, ActivityThatYouWantToGoTo.class);
n.putExtra("dataThatYouWantToPass", data);
startActivity(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setPackage("com.bushraod.sendM.hom");
intent.putExtra("name", nam);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
```

**Note:** Please try with this.